# My game has removed by Google (Graphic meta data violation). How do I fix it?

Tags: unity-game-engine, google-play, metadata

Google play removed by Game which was build by Unity3d .

Your app contains content that doesn't comply with the Metadata policy. The flagged content in your store listing relates to graphic violence prominently depicted in app icons, promotional images, text, or videos

I don't understand what is problem with my Graphic. I have used only royalty free assets .
I got problem with feature graphic and they removed my Game .

Feature Graphic [image: How to fix violation in this image]
Screenshot [image: How to fix violation in this image]

Comment: Please share app icons, promotional images, text title, description, short description, and videos if available. I think the problem is not from these images

Answer (score 0):

Don't make it look violent, I mean it seems like the player is shooting someone which might be the reason instead capture some great screenshots of your game then add some text and edit it and then upload it. But make sure that your image comply with these conditions.

> These are what said by Google :

Here are some examples of inappropriate text, images, or videos within your listing:
Imagery or videos with sexually suggestive content. Avoid suggestive imagery containing breasts, buttocks, genitalia, or other fetishized anatomy or content, whether illustrated or real.
Using profane, vulgar, or other language that is inappropriate for a general audience in your app’s Store listing.
Graphic violence prominently depicted in app icons, promotional images, or videos.
Depictions of the illicit usage of drugs. Even EDSA (Educational, Documentary, Scientific, or Artistic) content must be suitable for all audiences within the store listing.

Metadata Policy : https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9898842